# Alternatives to CSS Calc()? Can LESS or SASS do percent to pixel calculations?

Tags: css, sass, less, stylus

I've been looking for a while for a way to do percent to pixel calculations without using calc().  I'd love to be able to use calc but currently mobile safari (ios) does not support it before ios6.  Is there a way to do this in LESS?  I know you can do calculations but as far as I can tell you cant do something like 100% - 20px.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Not a universal solution, but depending upon what you're trying to accomplish (reading between the lines in your example seems like you're trying to do percentage sized containers with px padding) [`box-sizing: border-box`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/box-sizing) can be useful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No.

I spent a while searching for this when I first discovered about LESS, and I'm afraid it's impossible. LESS doesn't include a rendering engine and therefore has no way to work out exactly how wide a percentage of a parent element is going to be. Especially because quite often that parent element might be of variable width.

If the parent is of fixed width you can of course use LESS to calculate the pixels for you:

```
@containerWidth: 500px;
.container {width: @containerWidth;}
.child {width: @containerWidth / 5;}
```

Comment: This is the answer I was afraid of.  Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

neither LESS nor SASS can do calculations post-render.  The calculations they do are to render the initial CSS file that the browser then interprets.  They both generate 100% valid CSS.  Anything that CSS can do, SASS and LESS can both output (but usually with less verbosity and hair-pulling); However, if there is no way for CSS to do it, then there is no way for SASS or LESS to do it.

You might be able to get away with using Javascript:

```
$('some-element').css('margin-left', $('.my-element').width() - 15)
```

Comment: Well there is a way for CSS to do it [link](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#calc).  Sounds like I'm out of luck though until browsers catch up to the spec.

Comment: Ya i'm aware of the calc(), but you can't rely on that right now since it has such low browser penetration.